# IvParameterSpec value different for each print

Tags: java, linux, encryption

When trying to understand a problem I faced an interesting problem. The `IvParameterSpec class` cannot hold the IV fixed. It changes for every `println`.

I am using the javac 10.0.2 version on Ubuntu Linux

```
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Encryptor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IvParameterSpec ctr_iv;

        String IV = "0102030405060708";

        byte [] counter = IV.getBytes();

        ctr_iv = new IvParameterSpec(counter);
        System.out.println("ctr_iv = "+  ctr_iv.getIV());
        System.out.println("ctr_iv = "+  ctr_iv.getIV());
        System.out.println("ctr_iv = "+  ctr_iv.getIV());
        System.out.println("ctr_iv = "+  ctr_iv.getIV());
        System.out.println("ctr_iv = "+  ctr_iv.getIV());
        System.out.println("ctr_iv = "+  ctr_iv.getIV());
   }
}
```

Each of the `println` prints different values.

```
ctr_iv       = [B@42f30e0a
ctr_iv       = [B@24273305
ctr_iv       = [B@5b1d2887
ctr_iv       = [B@46f5f779
ctr_iv       = [B@1c2c22f3
ctr_iv       = [B@18e8568
```

What is the problem here? Shouldn't the values be the same?

Comment: You would expect `IvParameterSpec` to behave like an immutable class. The only way to do so is to return a *copy* of its underlying byte[] array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/IvParameterSpec.html#getIV--) of the method `IvParameterSpec.getIV()`:

> Returns a new array each time this method is called.

So your assumption that the values should be the same might be true, but it is always a *new* array.